# Finding Points in Polygons

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have a database with one table (ca_licenses) of business addresses and a second table in the public schema (ca_la_la_council) of city council district polygons.

I'm running this query to place the district number from the council table inside the business address table:

```
UPDATE poursafe.ca_licenses dst
SET prem_council = div_city
FROM public.ca_la_la_council src
WHERE st_within(dst.geom,src.geom) AND dst.geom&&src.geom;
```

My problem is I keep getting zero results. Both geom columns are geometry type and the SRID is 4326.

```
#create poursafe.ca_licenses table

CREATE TABLE ca_licenses (
id INTEGER,
license VARCHAR,
lat DOUBLE PRECISION,
lon DOUBLE PRECISION,
geom GEOMETRY,
prem_council VARCHAR
);

#create public.ca_la_la_council table

CREATE TABLE ca_la_la_council (
gid INTEGER,
div_city VARCHAR,
shape_leng NUMERIC,
shape_area NUMERIC,
geom GEOMETRY
);
```

Sample ca_licenses data: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PourSafe/data_samples/master/ca_licenses.csv

Sample ca_la_la_council data: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PourSafe/data_samples/master/ca_la_la_council.csv

I need to populate the ca_licenses table column 'prem_council' with the council district number 'div_city'. To do this I'm running the above query which finds which council district the ca_licenses points lie within.

I created a spatial_ref_sys table for the public.ca_la_la_district table but, do not have a spatial_ref_sys table for the ca_licenses table. Do I need one for this table as well? I believe the SRID for both geom columns is set at 4326.

I'm using postgis 2.4.4 and postgres 9.2 on a centos 7 setup.

Comment: Could you also provide 1) create table statements for these tables, 2) some sample data and 3) the expected result. This will **significantly** your chances to get an answer ;-) cheers!

Comment: I updated the original question with all of the above. Thanks!

Comment: I just created your environment: the geometries are **very** far away from each other and do not overlap at all, and as I can see the first condition in your where clause is **ST_Within**, which in this case will always return **false**. Using QGIS you could see it with more details. Write a comment if you need help with it.

Comment: You were very helpful Jim Jones. I had (assumed) the council SRID was 4326 when in fact it was 2229. I altered the projection with the below and all works great. Thanks!: 

ALTER TABLE public.ca_la_la_council ALTER COLUMN geom TYPE geometry(Polygon,4326)
        USING ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(geom,2229),4326);

Comment: I guess it should become the first rule of GIS: in case the geometries do not match, check SRS or coordinate pair order (*x,y* <> *y,x*). Glad it helped :-) Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

**First**

i want to recommend you to check [QGIS](https://qgis.org/en/site/)

works great with [wine](https://www.winehq.org/) 
on linux machines

**second**

there isn't any problem with your code after loading polygons file into qgis
this is the shapefile structure

[image]

and then i loaded the points file

[image]

the problem is that there isn't any intersection between them the cause is probably a wrong construction of the points.

(the little pink dot its the **ca_licenses.csv** points)

Last thing from my experiance the best way to intersect polygons with points is using [ST_INTERSECT](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Intersects.html)

```
select * from ca_licenses join ca_la_la_council on st_intersects(ca_licenses.geom,ca_la_la_council.geom)
```